# Android: Integrate Skype SDK to message/call without Skype client app installed

Tags: android, skype, skypedeveloper

I would like to develop an Android App to initiate Skype message/calls to actual skype users. But I don’t want to install Skype client App on the device. All the conversation have to be done within my Android App. I want to create my own UI for the conversation but want to use Skype SDK in the background to communicate between two or more users. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Skype SDK states that it works only with the Skype client. Skype does not have open protocol or API.

Comment: Did you can use skype for bussiness? if yes, tell me to tell you one solution for this